# Windows Python How to download dropbox popup from a website?

Tags: python, windows, redirect, download, dropbox

Alright so the issue is that I visit a site to download the file I want but the problem is the website that I try to download the file from doesn't host the actual file instead it uses dropbox to host it so as soon as you click download your redirected to a blank page that has dropbox pop up in a small window allowing you to download it. Things to note, there is no log in so I can direct python right to the link where dropbox pops up but it wont download the file.

```
import urllib

url = 'https://thewebsitedownload.com' 

filename = 'filetobedownloaded.exe'  
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Thats the code I use to use and it worked like a charm for direct downloads but now when I try to use it for the site that has the dropbox popup download it just ends up downloading the html code of the site (from what I can tell) and does not actually download the file.
I am still relatively new to python/ coding in general but I am loving it so far this is just the first brick wall that I have hit that I didn't find any similar resolutions to.
Thanks in advance! Sample codes help so much thats how I have been learning so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) to parse the html you get. You can then get the href link to the file. There are a lot of Beautifulsoup tutorials on the web, so I think you'll find it fairly easy to figure out how to get the link in your specific situation.

First you download the html with the code you already have, but without the filename:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://thewebsitedownload.com' 

text = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
link = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("dropbox"))[0]['href']
print link
filename = 'filetobedownloaded.exe'
urllib.urlretrieve(link, filename)
```

I made this from the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but haven't tested it, but I think you get the idea.